# Initramfs post-update hook

Tags: debian, initramfs

I need an initramfs hook to call a script after an initramfs has been
generated.

The [Debian Linux Kernel
Handbook](https://kernel-team.pages.debian.net/kernel-handbook/ch-update-hooks.html#s-initramfs-hooks)
mentions `/etc/initramfs/post-update.d/`:

> Packages for boot loaders that need to be updated whenever the files they
> load are modified must also install hook scripts in
> `/etc/initramfs/post-update.d`.
> […]
> The arguments given to these hook scripts are the kernel ABI version and the
> absolute path to the initramfs image.

This is exactly what I need, but this directory doesn't exist on my system.
Though the directory `/etc/initramfs-tools/` exists, but it doesn't contain
a `post-update.d`.

Where is the correct place to hook in such a script?

OS: Debian sid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have Debian stable, not sid, but it looks the same as what you describe so I think this answer is good for both.

The `post-update.d` directory doesn't exist in a default installation, but it is still checked by the `update-initramfs` script. The script doesn't distinguish between "nonexistent directory" and "exists but is empty". The intention is that if you are installing a bootloader that needs this functionality, you can just go ahead and create the directory yourself. The `lilo` and `elilo` packages do this, for example. Install one or both of those packages and you'll have an example to look at.

Comment: You're totally right, indeed. I assumed the mechanism had changed and the hook moved to a different place.