# Copy initramfs to a specific place after build?

Tags: ubuntu, initramfs

I've been hacking on a Raspberry Pi with an Ubuntu 15.04 image. Since I've got an encrypted boot setup, I need to generate an `initramfs.gz` image in the first partition of the filesystem, which is the plaintext boot device.

Ubuntu automatically generates initramfs images in `/boot/initrd.img-$(uname -r)`. Is there a hook that I can catch with a script so I can automatically copy the latest built image over to `/boot/firmware/initramfs.gz`?

Comment: initramfs is cpio - just put your root together in `.`, then [`find .|cpio -o -H newc | gzip > ../initramfs_data.cpio.gz`](http://landley.net/writing/rootfs-howto.html)

Answer (score 2):

Read [initramfs-tools manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man8/initramfs-tools.8.html) and write a hook script.  You can look at system supplied scripts placed in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/` for your reference.  Your own script should go in `/etc/initramfs-tools/hooks/`.  Scripts in both folders are merged and executed resolving its dependencies by `mkinitramfs`.

In a temporary folder, you can generate initramfs and examine its contents.

```
mkinitramfs -o initramfs.gz
zcat initramfs.gz | cpio -id initramfs.gz
```

Once it looks ready, update system initramfs in `/boot` using `update-initramfs -u`.

**EDIT:** I misunderstood your problem.

You can see hook script dirs in `/etc/kernel` which are called by postinst/postrm/preinst/prerm scripts of each kernel package.  `update-initramfs` is invoked in `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools`, so you can add another script there which will be called after `initramfs-tools`.

Comment: IIRC, the hooks are executed _during_ build of the initramfs. I'm looking for something which executes after the build is completed with preferably an environment variable pointing to the new image. Can I do that with a hook like that? I could just use a hook, does it pass the kernel version in?

Comment: Worse yet, calling `mkinitramfs` from an initramfs hook will likely cause an endless loop and crash the system, fill the process tree, and fill the disk.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your problem, sorry for that.  It would be difficult to do in the hook script.  Symlinks are not useful either?

Comment: A symlink isn't useful, unfortunately, as it's on a different block device.

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay Updated my answer.  Use `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/` hooks.

Answer (score 1):

I know, this is an old question, but I was looking for an answer to the same question and this is it:

Use a script in `/etc/initramfs/post-update.d/`

It isn't well documented for Ubuntu but [it is for Debian](https://kernel-team.pages.debian.net/kernel-handbook/ch-update-hooks.html) as described in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83545/initramfs-post-update-hook). The `update-initramfs` script checks if that directory exists and runs scripts in that directory after creating the initramfs.

First create the directory:

```
mkdir -p /etc/initramfs/post-update.d
```

And in your case the script would be:

```
/etc/initramfs/post-update.d/zz-copy-to-firmware

#!/bin/sh
cp /boot/initrd.img-$(uname -r) /boot/firmware/initramfs.gz
```

and make it executable:

```
chmod +x /etc/initramfs/post-update.d/zz-copy-to-firmware
```

Note: Ubuntu creates a symlink to the latest initramfs in `/boot/initrd.img`, so you could use that in the script instead of querying `uname -r`.